# Regex for Removing All the repetation of a string and assign to an array

Tags: c#, .net, regex, arrays

I have the following text in a file:

> "SHOP_ORDER001","SHOP_ORDER002","SHOP_ORDER003","SHOP_ORDER004","SHOP_ORDER005"

Now I am getting the values by reading the file and assigning to array by spilt:

```
 String orderValue = "";
 string[] orderArray;
 orderValue = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\File.txt");
 orderArray = orderValue.Split(',');
```

But I am getting the values as :
[image]

I need the Values in Array as "ORDER001","ORDER002","ORDER003"

Comment: Looks all fine to me... ` \ `  is the escape character, so `"\"xx\""` results in the output `"xxx"`

Comment: I don't think this possible because this is an escape character.
but when you assign it to a textbox.text for example it will be as you want.
could you enplane why do you need this?

Comment: @StephanBauer, Also want to remove SHOP_

Comment: Alright, must have missed that requirement :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\"` you see is just added by debugger visualizer for strings (because quote is a special characted and need to be escaped to don't get confused), don't worry they're not in your `orderArray`.

In case you want to remove quotes too so that your array will be:

```
SHOP_ORDER001
SHOP_ORDER002
...
```

Just use this (with LINQ):

```
var orderArray = orderValue.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim('"'));
```

By the way `String.Split` isn't very robust unless you're **sure** each field will never contain a comma.

**EDIT**
To answer the point you added in the comments if you need to remove `SHOP_` just write this:

```
var orderArray = orderValue.Split(',')
    .Select(x => x.Trim('"').Substring("SHOP_".Length));
```

Comment: This is a good answer. You don't need a RegEx to remove a well known and placed string.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Tnx, a simple substring will be slightly faster than a regex in this case (of course LINQ will waste any performance gain but the point is that at first look it _should_ be more clear than a regex)

Comment: I think `Replace` instead of `Substring` would be better here.  This use of `Substring` gives the false impression that it removes "SHOP_" from the beginning when it really just removes the first 5 characters regardless of what they are.

Comment: @juharr field format is fixed and SHOP_ will always be at the beginning of the string, _this is the reason we don't need a regex_ here (in case of variability I would prefer a regex too). Moreover Replace will remove the string regardless of _where it is_.

Comment: @Adriano If you can assume the format always has SHOP_ at the beginning is it that much of a stretch to assume it is ONLY at the beginning?

Comment: @juharr then you don't need to _search_ at all... (I mean: if we're sure about something then we don't need to guess or search, just assume it as valid and stable, if not then it's better to throw everything away and use regex)

Answer (score 3):

use this regex

```
var res = Regex.Matches(orderValue, @"(?<=""SHOP_)[^""]+?(?="")");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
string[] result = Regex.Split(orderValue, "(?:^\"SHOP_)|(?:\",\"SHOP_)|(?:\"$)");
```

However you will have to skip the first and last items in the resulting array as they will always be empty strings.

Answer (score -1):

Silly question but why don't you just do

```
.Replace("SHOP_", "");
```

Comment: Because you would still have the " at the start and end of each value.

Comment: @MartinBrown I believe he wanted the quotes. He just thought that there were double quotes it seems. The next part of the question was to remove SHOP_

Comment: @happygillmore because I think you are wrong about the quotes and your answer does not end up with an array which is also requested in the question.

Comment: the SO already worked out how to make an array using `Split`, his question was clearly directed at removing the SHOP_ text. Whether he wanted the quotes in is unclear to at least one other person here, so it's his responsibility to clarify. Downvote unfair.

Comment: If you were then to go on and split the string ie .Replace("SHOP_").Split(',') you would be processing the string twice which isn't very effecient.